# reading text into R with xml problems

Tags: r

**Summary at bottom of post**

**PART 1:**
I am trying to modify a function to fit my data however I run into the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
* Length 0: Columns `node`, `text`
* Length 2: Column `nid`
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.
```

Part of the function I am trying to run:

```
parse10k <- function(uri) {
  # 10-K HTML files are very flat with a long list of nodes. This pulls all
  # the relevant nodes.
  nodes <- read_html(uri) %>% 
    html_nodes('text') %>% 
    xml_children()
  nodes <- nodes[xml_name(nodes) != "hr"]

  # Unfortunately there isn't much of a workaround to this loop - we need
  # to track position in the file so it has to be a bit sequential...
  doc.parts <- tibble(nid = seq(length(nodes)),
                      node = nodes,
                      text = xml_text(nodes) ) %>% 
    filter(text != "") # way to get columns defined properly
}
```

Run the function:

```
data2 <- df %>%
  rename_(ID = ".id") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(grepl(".htm", doc.href, fixed = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(!grepl(".html", doc.href, fixed = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(nodes = map(doc.href, parse10k)) %>%
  #select(-accession_number, -href, -mdlink, -doc.href, -reportLink) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(filing_date)
```

ERROR:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
* Length 0: Columns `node`, `text`
* Length 2: Column `nid`
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.
```

**PART 2**
The problem seems to be because of a few links: I have taken everything out of the function previously defined and ran each link through it and the suspicious link is the following: (code at bottom of PART 2)

"bad" link:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312515272806/d918813d10k.htm

Which returns a data frame of `parts` of 110 observations...

```
# A tibble: 110 x 2
     nid text     
   <dbl> <chr>    
 1     0 PART 0   
 2    21 "PART I "
 3    26 "PART I "
 4    41 "PART I "
 5    66 "PART I "
 6    93 "PART I "
 7   126 "PART I "
 8   147 "PART I "
 9   171 "PART I "
10   191 "PART I "
# ... with 100 more rows
```

Whereas this link:

"good" link:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581009000013/fy2009form10k.htm

Returns the correct number of `parts`.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
    nid text   
  <dbl> <chr>  
1     0 PART 0 
2    65 PART I 
3   651 PART II
4   693 NA
```

This is the code which I run the links through:

```
url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312515272806/d918813d10k.htm"
nodes <- NULL; doc.parts <- NULL; parts <- NULL
nodes <- read_html(url) %>%
html_nodes('text') %>%
xml_children()
nodes <- nodes[xml_name(nodes) != "hr"]
doc.parts <- tibble(nid = seq(length(nodes)),
                     node = nodes,
                     text = xml_text(nodes) ) %>%
   filter(text != "")
parts <- doc.parts %>%
   filter(grepl("^part",text, ignore.case=TRUE)) %>%
   select(nid,text)
#  mutate(next.nid = c(nid[-1],length(nodes)+1)) %>%
if (parts$nid[1] > 1) {
   parts <- bind_rows(tibble(nid = 0, text= "PART 0"), parts)
}
parts <- bind_rows(parts,
                    tibble(nid = doc.parts$nid[length(doc.parts$nid)] + 1,
                           text = "NA"))
```

**PART 3** 
I have also looked at the `doc.parts` data frames and they are different. Under the column `node` the "good" link looks like:

```
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <title>fy2009form10k.htm</title>\n
[2] <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MAR ...
[3] <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MAR ...
[4] <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MAR ...
[5] <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MAR ...
[6] <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MAR ...
```

Whereas the "bad" link looks like:

```
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <title>10-K</title>\n
[2] <h5 align="left"><a href="#toc">Table of Contents</a></h5>
[3] <div style="width:97%; margin-top:1.5%; margin-left:1.5%; margin-ri ...
[4] <p style="page-break-before:always">\n</p>\n
[5] <h5 align="left"><a href="#toc">Table of Contents</a></h5>
[6] <div style="width:97%; margin-top:1.5%; margin-left:1.5%; margin-ri ...
```

So something is going wrong at the part here in the function (from part 1):

```
doc.parts <- tibble(nid = seq(length(nodes)),
                    node = nodes,
                    text = xml_text(nodes) ) %>%
  filter(text != "")
```

Specifically with the `xml_text(nodes)` part.

Question: Is there a way to know before hand which might be the "bad" links? - I have tried to remove all `.txt` and `.html` links which might not be able to be read in by the function but some of the `.htm` links are causing problems. - I would prefer not to remove them but if need be I will. Would a `tryCatch()` be useful here?

**PART 4** Since the webpages are different I am obtaining different list lengths when I run the links again through a for loop.

```
links <- c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/000002741914000014/tgt-20140201x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090012/000095013409003904/d66379e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312511200680/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312504150689/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27904/000002790417000004/dal1231201610k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746912001478/a2207295z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746905006608/a2152901z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/000104746910002121/a2196751z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/98246/000095012309005683/y75075e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/000081847914000004/dentsply201310-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581009000013/fy2009form10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312515272806/d918813d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746913001494/a2212713z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581015000036/nvda-2015x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581011000015/fy2011form10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090012/000119312514076267/d656849d10k.htm"
)
```

When I run this for loop

```
nodes <- NULL; doc.parts <- NULL; parts <- NULL


for(link in links){
nodes[[link]] <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes('text') %>%
  xml_children()
nodes[[link]] <- nodes[xml_name(nodes[[link]]) != "hr"]
doc.parts[[link]] <- tibble(nid = seq(length(nodes)),
                    node = nodes)
                    #text = xml_text(nodes) ) %>%
  #filter(text != "")

}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xml_text") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_text' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Which might be also causing the problem with the function.

However if I comment out the problem lines I do not get an error:

```
for(link in links){
nodes[[link]] <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes('text') %>%
  xml_children()
nodes[[link]] <- nodes[xml_name(nodes[[link]]) != "hr"]
doc.parts[[link]] <- tibble(nid = seq(length(nodes[[link]])))
                    #node = nodes[[link]])
                    #text = xml_text(nodes[[link]]) ) %>%
  #filter(text != "")

}
```

Where `doc.parts` is a list of different lengths.

I think the main problem comes from the web pages being different and the function doesn`t know how to deal with one kind of web page and this is also affecting this part.

#

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(.id = c("TGT", "DVN", "XRAY", "XRAY", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "DAL", "AON", "AON", "TGT", "TGT", "TIF", "XRAY", "NVDA", 
"MSFT", "AON", "MSFT", "NVDA", "NVDA", "DVN"), accession_number = c("0000027419-14-000014", 
"0000950134-09-003904", "0000818479-04-000031", "0000818479-99-000003", 
"0001193125-11-200680", "0001193125-04-150689", "0000027904-17-000004", 
"0001047469-12-001478", "0001047469-05-006608", "0001047469-10-002121", 
"0001047469-98-015191", "0000950123-09-005683", "0000818479-14-000004", 
"0001045810-09-000013", "0001193125-15-272806", "0001047469-13-001494", 
"0000891020-95-000433", "0001045810-15-000036", "0001045810-11-000015", 
"0001193125-14-076267"), act = c("34", "34", NA, NA, "34", NA, 
"34", "34", "34", "34", NA, "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", NA, 
"34", "34", "34"), file_number = c("001-06049", "001-32318", 
"000-16211", "000-16211", "000-14278", "000-14278", "001-05424", 
"001-07933", "001-07933", "001-06049", "001-06049", "001-09494", 
"000-16211", "000-23985", "000-14278", "001-07933", "000-14278", 
"000-23985", "000-23985", "001-32318"), filing_date = structure(c(1394751600, 
1235689200, 1079305200, 922744800, 1311804000, 1093989600, 1486940400, 
1330038000, 1110927600, 1268348400, 892591200, 1238364000, 1392850800, 
1236898800, 1438293600, 1361487600, 811983600, 1426114800, 1300230000, 
1393542000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), accepted_date = structure(c(1394751600, 
1235689200, 1079305200, 922744800, 1311804000, 1093989600, 1486940400, 
1330038000, 1110841200, 1268348400, 892591200, 1238364000, 1392850800, 
1236898800, 1438293600, 1361487600, 811983600, 1426028400, 1300230000, 
1393542000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), href = c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/000002741914000014/0000027419-14-000014-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090012/000095013409003904/0000950134-09-003904-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/000081847904000031/0000818479-04-000031-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/0000818479-99-000003-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312511200680/0001193125-11-200680-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312504150689/0001193125-04-150689-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27904/000002790417000004/0000027904-17-000004-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746912001478/0001047469-12-001478-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746905006608/0001047469-05-006608-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/000104746910002121/0001047469-10-002121-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/0001047469-98-015191-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/98246/000095012309005683/0000950123-09-005683-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/000081847914000004/0000818479-14-000004-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581009000013/0001045810-09-000013-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312515272806/0001193125-15-272806-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746913001494/0001047469-13-001494-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/0000891020-95-000433-index.html", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581015000036/0001045810-15-000036-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581011000015/0001045810-11-000015-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090012/000119312514076267/0001193125-14-076267-index.htm"
), type = c("10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", 
"10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", 
"10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K"), film_number = c("14693644", 
"09639574", "04670190", "99578860", "11993262", "041011640", 
"17600107", "12638817", "05683013", "10676542", "98594743", "09714434", 
"14630484", "09677521", "151019135", "13634337", "95575998", 
"15694143", "11692266", "14653539"), form_name = c("Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", "Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]", 
"Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K Item 405]"), description = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    size = c("20 MB", "2 MB", "687 KB", "309 KB", "16 MB", "1 MB", 
    "14 MB", "22 MB", "2 MB", "6 MB", "201 KB", "1 MB", "35 MB", 
    "4 MB", "14 MB", "24 MB", "189 KB", "16 MB", "19 MB", "41 MB"
    ), doc.href = c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/000002741914000014/tgt-20140201x10k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090012/000095013409003904/d66379e10vk.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/000081847904000031/f102003.txt", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/", "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312511200680/d10k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312504150689/d10k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27904/000002790417000004/dal1231201610k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746912001478/a2207295z10-k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746905006608/a2152901z10-k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/000104746910002121/a2196751z10-k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/", "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/98246/000095012309005683/y75075e10vk.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/000081847914000004/dentsply201310-k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581009000013/fy2009form10k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312515272806/d918813d10k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746913001494/a2212713z10-k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/", "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581015000036/nvda-2015x10k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581011000015/fy2011form10k.htm", 
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090012/000119312514076267/d656849d10k.htm"
    ), mdlink = c("[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/000002741914000014/0000027419-14-000014-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090012/000095013409003904/0000950134-09-003904-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/000081847904000031/0000818479-04-000031-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/0000818479-99-000003-index.html)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312511200680/0001193125-11-200680-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312504150689/0001193125-04-150689-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27904/000002790417000004/0000027904-17-000004-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746912001478/0001047469-12-001478-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746905006608/0001047469-05-006608-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/000104746910002121/0001047469-10-002121-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/0001047469-98-015191-index.html)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/98246/000095012309005683/0000950123-09-005683-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/000081847914000004/0000818479-14-000004-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581009000013/0001045810-09-000013-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312515272806/0001193125-15-272806-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746913001494/0001047469-13-001494-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/0000891020-95-000433-index.html)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581015000036/0001045810-15-000036-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581011000015/0001045810-11-000015-index.htm)", 
    "[Filing Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090012/000119312514076267/0001193125-14-076267-index.htm)"
    ), reportLink = c("[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/000002741914000014/tgt-20140201x10k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090012/000095013409003904/d66379e10vk.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/000081847904000031/f102003.txt)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312511200680/d10k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312504150689/d10k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27904/000002790417000004/dal1231201610k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746912001478/a2207295z10-k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746905006608/a2152901z10-k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/000104746910002121/a2196751z10-k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27419/)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/98246/000095012309005683/y75075e10vk.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/000081847914000004/dentsply201310-k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581009000013/fy2009form10k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312515272806/d918813d10k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315293/000104746913001494/a2212713z10-k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581015000036/nvda-2015x10k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581011000015/fy2011form10k.htm)", 
    "[10-K Link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090012/000119312514076267/d656849d10k.htm)"
    )), row.names = c(64L, 158L, 143L, 148L, 90L, 97L, 109L, 
24L, 31L, 68L, 80L, 49L, 133L, 10L, 86L, 23L, 106L, 4L, 8L, 153L
), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT1: Some packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(purrr)
library(edgarWebR)
library(rvest)
library(devtools)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
```

**EDIT2: (Summary)**

The problem I am running into is that I am trying to read in a number of `.htm` links. For the most of the links everything runs smoothly and correctly however when there are some "bad" links in the list of links the whole function throws out an error. I have analysed the problem and I think that the error is coming from one part of the code, specifically this part `doc.parts` and the fact that the code is trying to read two different HTML/XML code.

Using the "bad" URL the format of `doc.parts` - `node column` looks like the following:

```
> head(doc.parts$node)
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <title>10-K</title>\n
[2] <h5 align="left"><a href="#toc">Table of Contents</a></h5>
[3] <div style="width:97%; margin-top:1.5%; margin-left:1.5%; margin-ri ...
[4] <p style="page-break-before:always">\n</p>\n
[5] <h5 align="left"><a href="#toc">Table of Contents</a></h5>
[6] <div style="width:97%; margin-top:1.5%; margin-left:1.5%; margin-ri ...
```

Which is causing all kinds of problems. However when I run the "good" URL the same column looks like the following:

```
> head(doc.parts$node)
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <title>fy2009form10k.htm</title>\n
[2] <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MAR ...
[3] <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MAR ...
[4] <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MAR ...
[5] <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MAR ...
[6] <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MAR ...
```

Which the rest of the function can handle. I think it will be too complex to write some code to read in the "bad" URLS and there seems to be only a few of them. I think it might be better to just forget the bad URLs somehow.

**EDIT 3:**
The following "bad" url reads in as a `large xml_nodes` object.

```
url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312515272806/d918813d10k.htm"

nodes <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('text') %>%
  xml_children()
```

The "good" url reads in as a list of 692

```
url2 <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581009000013/fy2009form10k.htm"

nodes2 <- read_html(url2) %>%
  html_nodes('text') %>%
  xml_children()
```

Comment: That's a comprehensive post! Can't you abstract away and provide a simplified version of the underlying problem?

Comment: Sure! I will edit the post and provide a summary at the bottom!

Comment: I added something, let me know if its still unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of the code that I believe is trying to be used here from exploration I did back in 2007 processing HTML of SEC filings - https://micah.waldste.in/blog/2017/10/introduction-to-sentiment-analysis-of-10-k-reports-in-r/

tl;dr; Don't use this code, user the [edgarWebR](https://mwaldstein.github.io/edgarWebR/) R library which has built on this approach and is far more reliable for navigating the SEC site and parsing filing and forms.

For people who run into this or related issues though, let me call out a few of the bugs you're seeing.

## seq vs seq_along

I think that everyone gets caught by this at some point - in the code to create the table there is this block -

```
doc.parts <- tibble(nid = seq(length(nodes)),
                    node = nodes,
                    text = xml_text(nodes) ) %>%
...
```

The bug is that in the case you are encountering, `nodes` is length 0. `xml_text(nodes)` is also then length 0, but a very funny thing happens for `nid`... While we want it to also be length 0, `seq(0)` returns `c(1, 0)`, length 2...

Moral of the story: if you want identifiers for the items in a list, use `seq_along(nodes)` rather than `seq(length(nodes))` so it doesn't break in the 0-length case.

## Parsing SEC Docs is Bad

The other immediate question should be "well, why isn't the parsing giving any length? Having it create a result of 0 length is no good".

Unfortunately, SEC filings, while they standardized on HTML, are the ugliest, least standardized HTML on the planet. Every company does something a bit different or takes these "standardized forms" as an opportunity to "Brand". Parsing them is more an effort in brute force than in clever processing.

This is why the code you were trying would sometimes work and sometimes fails - depends on how exactly poorly formatted the specific filing is.

## Avoid the direct pain

Use the R [edgarWebR](https://mwaldstein.github.io/edgarWebR/) package if you're trying to parse SEC filings - we've been playing wack-a-mole with specific parsing problems - it isn't pretty, but it works.